# Getting Top 3 from Mysql table based on Condition/Value

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I need to get top 3 Forwards,Top 3 Midfielders,Top 4 Defenders based on Soccer players Position

i have separate table for Position

Structure of position table

PositionID And  PositionName

1     Tor(Which Means Goal Keeper)

2   Abwehr(Which Means Defenders)

3   Mittelfeld(Which Means Midfielders)

4   Angriff(Which Means Forwards)

and i have Soccerplayers Table where there is Name(Player Name),PositionId,TScore(Player Score)

i need Top 3 players from Each position based on TScore

any query suggestion ??

Comment: i cound'nt think of Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can try this query set:

```
(SELECT Name, PositionId, TScore FROM Soccerplayers WHERE PositionID = 1 ORDER BY TScore LIMIT 3)
UNION
(SELECT Name, PositionId, TScore FROM Soccerplayers WHERE PositionID = 2 ORDER BY TScore LIMIT 4)
UNION
(SELECT Name, PositionId, TScore FROM Soccerplayers WHERE PositionID = 3 ORDER BY TScore LIMIT 3)
```