# Get top x values in mysql table according to column value

Tags: mysql

I have the following table data:

```
content,count
'a', '1'
'b', '2'
'c', '2'
'd', '2'
'content_name', '18'
'de', '2'
'dea', '2'
'deaasdfdsaf', '5'
'content_name', '17'
```

I would like to have the correct query for getting x (for example 4) rows with the biggest values in their content column

I have tried the answers given in:
[Getting Top 3 from Mysql table based on Condition/Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22293721/getting-top-3-from-mysql-table-based-on-condition-value)
but it didnt work as i was expecting

it keeps giving me just the rows by their table location
any suggestions?

Comment: define "biggest"

Comment: `select * from table order by \`count\` desc limit 4`?

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Test(content varchar(100),count integer );
insert into Test(content, count) values("a", 1);
insert into Test(content, count) values("b", 2);
insert into Test(content, count) values("c", 2);
insert into Test(content, count) values("d", 2);
insert into Test(content, count) values("content_name", 18);
insert into Test(content, count) values("de", 2);
insert into Test(content, count) values("dea", 2);
insert into Test(content, count) values("deaasdfdsaf", 5);
insert into Test(content, count) values("content_name", 7);

select * from Test
order by count desc
limit 4;
```

However, I am not quite sure what you mean by *"biggest values in their content column"*, therefore I ranked by their count values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are actually looking for the number of character within the content column, which was my initial impression reading your question:

Using Martin Stagl's post to create the example table .

```
select *, LENGTH(REPLACE(content, 'N', '')) as char_length from Test;
```

NOTE: If this is not working on the server, try replacing the LENGTH() function with LEN()

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/032d48/9